# Mybatis map multiple column to same property

Tags: java, properties, multiple-columns, mybatis

My use case is something like this. I get some values from database, now I need to map the column names and the value into a java class using my batis.

Can this be achieved?

```
<select id="selectEmp" parameterType="int" >
select empName, empSal, empDesignation, empDOJ
FROM employee
where empId={empId}
```

My java class where I want it to be mapped looks like ths

```
public class Employee
{
   protected String propertyName;
   protected String propertyValue;

   //getters setters
}
```

propertyName would be empName
propertyName would be its value fetched from database.

Is this even possible? Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `java.util.Map` as your Mybatis's `resultType`, then you can get all the key's set and value's set through `java`'s method.

For example:

```
new HashMap<String, String>().keySet(); // This will get you all the keys which means 'propertyName'.
new HashMap<String, String>().values(); // This will get you all the values which means 'propertyValue'.
```